# Dotfuscator failing with error Invalid Input Assembly: abc.dl after migration to vs2015

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, dotfuscator

Dotfuscator failing with error  Invalid Input Assembly: abc.dl  Error encountered while loading module (abc.dll). Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Earlier my solution was building on vs2010 & .net Framework 4.0 and dotfuscator working as successfull.

Now we have migrated the project into vs2015 with .net framework 4.6.2 now dotfuscator failing with erorr  **Invalid Input Assembly: abc.dl  Error encountered while loading module (abc.dll). Index was outside the bounds of the array**

Below some points on project that might help you guys to give answer.

1. Using msbuild to build the soltion.
2. it has reference of .ocx files which also has been migrated to vs2015.
   Can anybody help me why this is happening. on what reason this error occures.

Comment: I work for PreEmptive Solutions (who make Dotfuscator). It sounds like this is Dotfuscator Community Edition (CE)? We don't usually provide direct support for CE, but this is probably a bug and we'd like to diagnose it. So I have a few things you can try: (1) Download the latest version of CE (for VS 2015) from [the downloads page](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads) and see if that fixes it. (2) Try a Pro evaluation (from that same page) and see if that fixes it. (3) Report your results to support at preemptive dot com, and we'll try to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for reply...i have tried with new version also but got same result

Comment: Ok i will raise the issue on forum.